# Access API controller from local machine

Tags: asp.net, api

Have a API written in .Net that is developed for use for numerous internal applications also written in .Net. The API also will serve external users at a much later time. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way for the local applications to access the API without needing to authenticate like an external would with a token.

So to make this make a bit more sense or try to:

- 2 local applications
- 1 local API

Call local API with jQuery yet not need to do a token validation of some sort since it is from local applications.  OAuth was in mind for external but not local.

I have tried

```
Request.IsLocal()
```

and an extension of this

```
public static bool IsLocal(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var localFlag = request.Properties["MS_IsLocal"] as Lazy<bool>;
        return localFlag != null && localFlag.Value;
    }
```

This works correctly when working locally but when I push both the API and app onto the testing server and call the app URL it always returns as it not being local.

Is there a way to tell the API controller to get what is accessing it to determine that it is a local app?

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

thanks
^.^